# Is it possible to synchronize actions in cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, callback, action, cocos2d-x

I need to run an action on a collection of nodes in cocos2d-x, and then run a callback when *all* those actions complete.

Eg. I have 20 objects, I want them to scale to a defined value, and when all these actions complete I want to update another object (let's call it a ball) on screen.

I tried attaching running the action on the ball prepending a fixed delay that should take into account the total execution time of the longest action from the list before. Even if this approach works fairly good, sometimes the delayed action is run before the last object from the first list complete its own. Moreover, the execution time of each one of those action could vary from time to time, so that fixed delay would be a guessed value for the worst case scenario. Not so good, in my opinion.

Is there a way in cocos2d-x to achieve this natively, using the provided APIs?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go about it something like this (in objc, hope the c++ sdk has similar features) :

```
    _animComletes = 0;                // must be an iVar
    _maxBalls     = [_nodes count];   // nust be an iVar

    for (CCNode *nn in _nodes) {
        id oneObject = [CCSequence actions:
                [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.25 scale:.35],
                [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
                    _animCompletes++;
                    if (_animCompletes == _maxBalls) {
                        [self scheduleOnce:@selector(updateBall) delay:0];
                    }

                }], nil];
        [nn runAction:oneObject];
    }

-(void) updateBall {
    _animCompletes = 0;
    _maxBalls = 0;
    // do your thing 
}
```

Comment: I'd though of something like that, but the action I will call on the object is defined in the object itself. Eg. I do not call `[nn runAction:]` but `[nn customAction]` via a custom function. I wondered if cocos2d/x had the possibility to group objects and listen for their actions to complete, without using custom counters and the like.

Comment: @marzapower - Well, there is  isDone() that returns a bool if the action has completed.

Comment: hmmm ... i would add a parameter to customAction , something like withCompletionBlock and pass the completion block via that to your custom.